# Scripts disappearing from Unity objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am relatively new to Unity and I was trying out the Unity Create With Code course. I am on Unit 3 and I created my player.

I later tried to add my PlayerController script to my player and it kept disappearing. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean disappearing? It doesn't show up in the inspector? The file gets deleted? You can't create it? Does Unity give you any error?  We need more info to be able to help you

Comment: you maybe adding script when Unity Editor is playing, first stop it, then add your script

Comment: We can't say what is happening if you don't post any code or anything of what is happening in your local computer. Also, what do you mean by "Unity 3"? Why would you use a so deprecated/legacy/old/abandoned version instead of the latest 2021.3 LTS version?

Comment: it is unit 3 of the create with code course: https://learn.unity.com/course/create-with-code

Comment: Also I added it before I pressed play